# encrypting / shortening a long string in JS

Tags: javascript, encoding, decoding

I need to shorten a long string with a variable length and "decode" it back later on.
The string will be built up like this `0011010011 ........ etc.`

My problem right now is that the string will be over a thousand characters long which is far far too long to easily copy and paste around.

Any ideas on how to do this?

[read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38071235/6519090)

Comment: Do you mean that the string only has the characters 0 and 1?

Comment: _encrypting_ is not the same as _encoding_. In this case I think you meant _encoding_.

Comment: Also, does the string have a length that is a multiple of 8? If so, you could parse each 8 bytes as a binary integer, and store it in a Uint8Array. That would yield a compression of 8 to 1.

Comment: Another way to go is to look into using some form of [Run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) if you expect the string to have long runs of 1s or 0s.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript doesn't support binary data by default. I would either use an exisiting package such as [binstring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binstring) or write your own encoding function